# Returning character input with assembly?

Tags: assembly, char, return

What I've (accidentally) made is an assembly program that echoes any input, no matter how long. As soon as I hit enter, the line I typed appears a second time, and there appears to be no return value.

```
initialize:
    set 0x00ffff00,r15      ! Initialize the stack reg
    set 0x00ffff00,r3       
    set 0x00ffff04,r4       

getCharacter:                  loop:
    load    [r3],r5         !     r5 := serial status word
    btst    0x00000001,r5   !     if status[charAvail] == 0 then
    be  getCharacter        !     go to getCharacter
    load    [r4],r2         !   Get the character
    store   r2,[r15+4]      !  put the character in the result position
    ret                     ! return the character
```

What I'm trying to do is similar, but I need it to read an input character, then return it without any echoes or prompts. I don't know if this is the right way to go about asking this question (my code isn't runnable without blitz to my knowledge), but I haven't found any other good resources for assembly.

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?

Comment: I'm on a linix/ubuntu machine. I'm using blitz as a learning tool for operating systems.

Comment: I've never heard of it...

Comment: Is this the full code? According to the comment the chars are read one at a time. However, if the emulator processes lines in cooked mode, the input is buffered until the first newline and then send to the emulator. You can change the line mode of the running terminal and see if the emulator can handle raw input.